# MySql count duplicates in column of a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `telco` which has 2 columns, `id(PK)` and `telco_prov`. I want to count the duplicate records in the `telco_prov` column, then display the number of times it appeared.

`telco` table example:

```
id    telco_prov
1     Smart
2     Smart
3     Globe
4     Globe
5     Globe
```

Here is my code:

```
    $query = "select telco_prov, count(*) c from telco group by telco_prov having c > 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error: '.mysql_error ());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo "SMART: <font color= 'red'>".$row['c']."</font>";
    echo "<br>GLOBE: <font color= 'red'>".$row['c']."</font>";
```

The code has no error, but it doesn't do the counting correctly.

The result from the code above:

```
SMART: 2
GLOBE: 2
```

But it should be:

```
SMART: 2
GLOBE: 3
```

I've tried adding `where` statement in the query but still it doesn't work.

```
$query = "select telco_prov, count(*) c from telco where telco_prov = 'Smart' group by telco_prov having c > 1";
```

Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you have two rows in your resultset, so you need to perform a loop in order to fetch all the records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to loop the results. see the below code

```
$query = "select telco_prov, count(*) c from telco group by telco_prov having c > 1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error: '.mysql_error ());
while($row = $mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['telco_prov'].": <font color= 'red'>".$row['c']."</font>";
}
```

Comment: no problem, just to ensure that entire code is correct. And one suggestion - in future better suggest `mysqli_*` functions to be used instead of already depreciated `mysql_*`. this will gain you more points and is proper way to give complete solutions.

Comment: @RavinderReddy I don't know what's still wrong with thecode, but still it doesn't return all of the records in my table.

Comment: @Gelly what is the output/result after using the above code?

Comment: @RavinderReddy the output is incomplete. In my case, the table contains 15 records, having: Globe (4 duplicates), Globe/TM(6 duplicates), Smart(2 duplicates), Sun Cellular(2 duplicates) and Smart/TNT/Addict Mobile(1). It only displays Globe/TM: 6
Smart: 2
Smart/TNT/Addict Mobile: 1
Sun Cellular: 2

Comment: try this query  $query = "select telco_prov, count(*) c from telco group by telco_prov having count(telco_prov) > 1";

Comment: I did that already, but still the result is incomplete. But when I tried select * from telco, all of the records are displayed. I'm pretty sure the problem is in the former query.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo strtoupper($row['telco_prov']).": <font color= 'red'>".$row['c']."</font>";
}
```

The code you write will give only the first row. **For getting all the records, you need to loop though the record**

Answer (score 0):

the error is here

```
echo "SMART: <font color= 'red'>".$row['c']."</font>";
echo "<br>GLOBE: <font color= 'red'>".$row['c']."</font>";
```

this code will echo all telco_prov with their counts

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo '"'.$row['telco_prod'].'"':<font color="red">'.$row['c'].'</font>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line from Reddy/mitkosoft made my day.

I have been looking for a query to find any duplicate values in a single column in a MySQL table.

This is what I used:

`$result = $conn->query("SELECT column, COUNT(*) c FROM table GROUP BY column HAVING c > 1");`

Does the trick!